# How are garbage values for variables generated in C?

Tags: c, variables, initialization, undefined-behavior

I mean to ask if it follows some specific algorithm and actually are not junk.

In other words, how exactly the "garbage" values be present? Considering not invoking UB, if a garbage value is read, what is the source of that value?

Comment: Garbage is garbage. If there was an algorithm it wouldn't be gargbage, it woud be "Specifically generated silly values with some known definable and probably reproducible pattern"

Comment: It's just what was there beforehand, therefore there is no overhead incurred setting it to a specified value. There is no algorithm.

Comment: Is there a definitive catch-all we can use on this site to mark questions about Undefined Behavior as duplicate?

Comment: What you are asking is probably why don't some variables get predefined values and you find garbage there if you do'n deliberately initialise them. This is mostly due to the fact that same memory location may be used after some other variable used it in the past and left its last value there. After power up uninitialised memory will also contain some garbage. So .... just initialise our data.

Comment: This question is probably a valid one, maybe not worded properly. Sadly, there's not enough googlable material for inexperienced people, IMHO. I'm not saying this is a very useful question but I'd not DV it, either. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard does not mention the term "garbage", it mentions "indeterministic / indeterminate values". The value can be *anything*.<sup>Note</sup>

From the user point of view, if we are unable to get a fix on a certain value (for any variable), then the "expectation" is not matched anytime and the value (if) we  get is not of any use, thus terming them as "garbage" is common.

The most relatable and common observation / implementation is, for an automatic variable left uninitialized, only the storage is allocated, the content of that storage is not touched. So, probably it still contains the **last stored value** which was put there. Now, that value, probably being a valid one in other (previous) scenario, in present case, does not make any sense, so it is "garbage" in current scenario.

**TL;DR** The "garbage" value is not *generated*, most of the cases, it's just the last stored value in that memory location.

---

Note:

Related quoting from `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, **its value is
>   indeterminate.** [....]

---

***§§ Additional Read:***

This is very closely related to the topic, so adding it as a footnote.

In case, there exist a variable, which holds indeterministic value and

- the data type can have trap representation
- the address of the variable is not taken

then, trying to read the value actually causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Be aware.

Comment: "anything" turns out to be more surprising than most people think it is. If the uninitialized variable is on the stack, it can contain an out-of-range value for that data type (or a trap value if the processor has one even if that data type doesn't).

Answer (score 3):

When C allocates memory on the stack and heap, it does not modify what's stored at the memory addresses, it simply designates the space for your variable. An un-initialized variable will contain whatever was in memory at that location before you declared the variable. Some times the values will be previous memory from your program that was used and cleared, and some times they will be values from the OS, stack canaries, etc. There is no way to predict what will be there.

Comment: Also, some C variables only live in processor registers, and their "garbage" value is the previously stored data in that register.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage values exist for variables on the stack (also known as automatic variable) if not initialized. They are pushed, popped, initialized with previous variable residing on the address in the stack, previous function call, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Every specific memory addresses (either stack or heap) will be having some data. Before assigning that memory to your variable, it might be used by another variable (may be by OS or other programs). So, it might contain last values assigned by those last allocated variables. And those values are now useless to us. Thats why they are garbage for us